# Feymann Kac for multidimensional pde

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde, sde, feynman-kac

I Have to solve the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}=0\\\\
F(t,x,y)=xy^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
My problem is the presence of the mixed derivative term and I don't have any Idea on how to manage it.
If the mixed derivative term is not present I know that I can introduce two independent brownian motion under the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and describe the dynamics of the process $X$ and $Y$ as:
\begin{equation}
dX_t=dW_t^1\\\\
dY_t=dW_t^2
\end{equation}
and then apply the formula:
\begin{equation}
F(t,X_t,Y_t)=E^\mathbb{P}_t[X_TY_T^2]=E_t^\mathbb{P}[X_T]E_t^\mathbb{P}[Y^2_T]
\end{equation}
If the mixed derivative is present I know that the two processes can be correlated in some ways but I'm not able to write explicitely the dynamic of the two processes calculations.
Can someone help me?

EDIT:
I've tried to reasoning like this: we can assume that the two processes evolves according the following dynamics with $W_1$ and $W_2$ independent Brownian Motions:
\begin{equation}
dX=\sigma_1dW_1\\
dY=\sigma_2(\rho dW_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}dW_2)
\end{equation}
Now lookind at the coefficients of the PDE we have $\sigma_1=1$, $\sigma_2=1$ and since the quadratic covariation should be still 1 it must be $\sigma_2\rho=1\Rightarrow\rho=1$. Hence in principal the two processes follows the same dynamic:
\begin{equation}
dX=dW_1\\
dY=dW_1
\end{equation}
Now this implies that the solution of the two SDEs are:
\begin{equation}
X_T=X_t+W_T^1-W_t^1\\
Y_T=Y_t+W_T^1-W_t^1
\end{equation}
Applying now Feymann-Kac we find:
\begin{equation}
F(t,X_t,Y_t)=E_t(X_TY_T^2)=E((X_t+\sqrt{T-t}Z_1)(Y_t^2+2Y_t\sqrt{T-t}Z_1+(T-t) Z_1^2))\\
=X_tY_t^2+X_t(T-t)+2Y_t(T-t)
\end{equation}
Where I used that $Z_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $E(Z_1^3)=0$ by the properties of gaussian density.
Now removing the stochasticity in the processes we find the solution:
\begin{equation}
F(t,x,y)=xy^2+(x+2y)(T-t)
\end{equation}
As sanity check I plug it into the Pde to find:
\begin{equation}
-x-2y+\frac{1}{2}2x+2y=0
\end{equation}
To conclude I have now to check that $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ and $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ are in $M^2(0,T)$ but I avoid this computation.

Comment: Are you sure the PDE is correct? Because it implies correlation is 1, and since all volatility terms are 1 as well, it basically says $X=Y$. Doesn't make much sense to me, unless I am missing something as well.

Comment: How can you deduce that the correlation is 1?

Comment: @FridoRolloos have uploaded some computation, do you think that it is fine?

Comment: Yes I think you've solved it. But as you can see $X_t = Y_t + c$ for some constant $c$.